# Clicking links with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm new to Python (I come from a PHP/JavaScript background), but I just wanted to write a quick script that crawled a website and all children pages to find all `a` tags with `href` attributes, count how many there are and then click the link. I can count all of the links, but I can't figure out how to "click" the links and then return the response codes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

def getLinks(url):
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    return links

anchors = getLinks("http://madisonmemorial.org/")
# Click on links and return responses
countMe = len(anchors)
for anchor in anchors:
    i = getLinks(anchor)
    countMe += len(i)
    # Click on links and return responses

print countMe
```

Is this even possible with `BeautifulSoup`?
Also, I'm not looking for exact code, all I'm really looking for is like a point in the right direction for function calls to use or something like that. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can't perform click actions with bs4, maybe take a look at selenium ? otherwise  you can use `urllib2.urlopen` with the new links ?

Comment: If you want to click on them just to get the response code you can just use `urllib2.urlopen` with the url in hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with help from the comments, I decided to just use urlopen like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

def getLinks(url):
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    return links

anchors = getLinks("http://madisonmemorial.org/")
for anchor in anchors:
    happens = urllib.request.urlopen(anchor)
    if happens.getcode() == "404":
        # Do stuff
# Click on links and return responses
countMe = len(anchors)
for anchor in anchors:
    i = getLinks(anchor)
    countMe += len(i)
    happens = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
    if happens.getcode() == "404":
        # Do some stuff

print(countMe)
```

I've got my own arguments in the if statements

Comment: I believe you're trying to do this https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: Scrapy is a more common web crawler, though

Answer (score 3):

`Urlopen` is a better solution for your purpose but if you need to click and interact with elements on the web I suggest using `selenium webdriver`. There are implementations for Java, Python, and other languages. I've used it with Java and Python, works pretty good. You can run it headless so the browser doesn't actually open.

```
pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 2):

`BeautifulSoup` is merely a DOM/HTML Parser, it doesn't constitute a real or in your case emulated browser. For that purpose you could use Chrome or Selenium to emulate a real browser and crawl freely, which gives you the advantage of handling **Javascript**, however when that's not needed, you can use the widely available package **[requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)** to recursively crawl all links:

```py
for link in links:
  body = requests.get(link).text
```

Comment: I agree with everything above that the mister said, I'd also like to add that what the asker might be looking for is working with the `requests` library, you can make all kind of requests ( get/post / del and such ) with the mentioned lib. However, this can't be done for JS (at least in a manner that's known to me). But let's say you want to register or log in or submit data. All of this can be done only with using `requests` or `urllib` and much faster than Selenium.